# Retornar último registro de una tabla relacionada Laravel 5.7

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Tengo dos tablas relacionas (materials y costs) donde materials puede estar relacionadas con muchos costs, dentro de costs tengo un atributo llamado valor. Lo que necesito hacer es retornar 5 registros de materials mas el ultimo registro de costs relacionada con materials. Por favor les pido su ayuda. De ante mano muchas gracias

```
public function buscar_nombre(Request $request)
{
    $materials = Material::with('costs')
                         ->where('nombre','LIKE','%'.$request->val.'%')    
                         ->take(5)->get()->toJson();
    return response($materials);
}
```

Comment: no termino de comprender lo que buscas obtener, si pudieras editar la pregunta y agregar una muestra de como deberían lucir los datos que deseas obtener, sería genial

Comment: Daniel, te invito a realizar el [tour] para que veas como funciona el sitio y ademas obtienes tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges). Adicionalmente te invito a revisar [ask] y [mcve]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tendrías que ejecutar dos querys, si o sí, ya que primero deseas obtener sólo 5 y después el último registro con relación a la tabla `materials`:

```
public function buscar_nombre(Request $request)
{
    //Los 5 que ya tienes
    $materials = Material::with('costs')
                         ->where('nombre','LIKE','%'.$request->val.'%')    
                         ->take(5)->get()->toJson();
    //El extra que necesitas:

    $last_cost = Costs::whereHas('material')->get()->last();

    //Tu código extra que necesites acá...
}
```

Podrías hacer un `union` pero a fin de cuenta son dos enunciados `select` de cualquier forma.